# What is this react functional component which returns functions instead of template?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Please can someone tell me what is such as react component that returns a bunch of functions and which uses react hooks inside of it ?

Even a react functional component is supposed to return jsx or any other template , no ?
Is such as component stated in react documentation ? how is it called ?!

```
export default function useViewFilter() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { boardId, viewId } = useParams<RouteParamsTypes>();
  const [selectedFacets, setSelectedFacets] = useState<SelectedFacets>({});
  const [propertiesData, setPropertiesData] = useState<PropertyData[]>([]);
  const [propertiesFacetingTypes, setPropertiesFacetingTypes] = useState<PropertiesFacetingTypes>({});
  const neededData = useSelector((state: IFrontAppState) => selectFilterHookNeededData(state, { boardId, viewId }));
  const isReady = useSelector((state: IFrontAppState) => isViewModelLoaded(state, boardId, viewId));
  const storeFacetsFilters = useSelector((state: IFrontAppState) => getViewFacetsFilters(state, boardId, viewId));
  const storeFacetingTypes = useSelector((state: IFrontAppState) =>
    getViewPropertiesFacetingTypes(state, boardId, viewId)
  );
  const dataRef = useRef({
    initialized: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    handleMakeNewSearch(selectedFacets, false);
  }, [neededData]);

  // last state before refresh
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isReady && !dataRef.current.initialized) {
      dataRef.current.initialized = true;
      setSelectedFacets(storeFacetsFilters ? (storeFacetsFilters as SelectedFacets) : {});
      setPropertiesFacetingTypes(storeFacetingTypes ? storeFacetingTypes : {});
      handleMakeNewSearch(storeFacetsFilters as SelectedFacets, false);
    }
  }, [isReady, storeFacetsFilters, storeFacetingTypes, dataRef]);

  const handleClear = () => {
    const selectedFacets = {};
    setSelectedFacets(selectedFacets);
    handleMakeNewSearch(selectedFacets, true);
    dispatch(
      actions.ClearViewFilters({
        BoardId: boardId,
        ViewId: viewId
      })
    );
  };

  const handleMakeNewSearch = (selectedFacets: SelectedFacets, doUpdateInBackend: boolean) => {
    const { propertiesIds, properties, orderedEntities, boardMembersObj } = neededData;
    if (properties && propertiesIds?.length) {
      const orderedProperties = propertiesIds?.map(pId => ({
        Id: pId,
        ...properties[pId]
      }));
      const itemsJsData = makeItemsJsDataFromAllEntities(orderedEntities, orderedProperties, boardMembersObj);
      const newSearchResult = makeSearchAggregations(itemsJsData, orderedProperties, selectedFacets);
      // set filtred items
      if (doUpdateInBackend) {
        const filtredEntitiesIds = newSearchResult.items.map(x => x.id) as string[];
        dispatch(
          actions.UpdateViewFilters({
            BoardId: boardId,
            ViewId: viewId,
            FacetsFilters: selectedFacets,
            FiltredEntitiesIds: doesThereIsFeltering(selectedFacets) ? filtredEntitiesIds : null,
            PropertiesFacetingTypes: propertiesFacetingTypes
          })
        );
      }
      // update filter panel
      const newPropertiesData = makeNewPropertiesData(
        propertiesIds,
        properties,
        newSearchResult.aggregations,
        propertiesFacetingTypes
      );
      setPropertiesData(newPropertiesData);
    }
  };

  return {
    propertiesData,
    propertiesFacetingTypes,
    handleClear,
    setPropertiesFacetingTypes
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html).

it's one of the ways (nowadays maybe the standard way) of extracting logic in React function components.